# Trying to recover permanently deleted emails from Google which were two years ago

Tags: gmail

I currently have an important criminal suit and am aware that there are some Gmail messages which can serve as crucial evidence in support of my stand. However, I realise that these Gmail messages (received two years ago, Dec 2015 or Jan 2016) have been deleted without my awareness and consent.  I suspected that the act was done by the defendant when he gained unauthorized access to my Gmail account early this year (Jan or Feb 2017).

Is any way I can retrieve these emails from Google, given that it might have been been some time. I am willing to pay a small fee to Google for executing this task.